# How to save image to device using expo

Tags: react-native, expo, mobile-development, imagepicker

i'm working on app in expo to take and save image to device. I tried camera roll but it seems it's not supported in expo
so is there any way to save image to device using expo

Comment: you need react-native-fs to save image to your storage

Answer (score 4):

Expo provides a package to save assets - https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/media-library/ (including images) to the device media library.

Storage access permission is required before attempting to save a file.

```js
// Top-level module import
import * as MediaLibrary from "expo-media-library";
const saveImage = async (uri) => {
  try {
    // Request device storage access permission
    const { status } = await MediaLibrary.requestPermissionsAsync();
    if (status === "granted") {
    // Save image to media library
      await MediaLibrary.saveToLibraryAsync(uri);

      console.log("Image successfully saved");
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

For taking a photo, Expo provides a plugin called [ImagePicker](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/v45.0.0/sdk/imagepicker/).

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Button, Image, View, Platform } from 'react-native';
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';

export default function ImagePickerExample() {
  const [image, setImage] = useState(null);

  const pickImage = async () => {
    // No permissions request is necessary for launching the image library
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 3],
      quality: 1,
    });

    console.log(result);

    if (!result.cancelled) {
      setImage(result.uri);
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Button title="Pick an image from camera roll" onPress={pickImage} />
      {image && <Image source={{ uri: image }} style={{ width: 200, height: 200 }} />}
    </View>
  );
}
```

You will also have to handle permissions.

If using a bare react native app, check out extra instructions [here](https://github.com/expo/expo/tree/main/packages/expo-image-picker).